# Optional capture of balanced brackets in Lua

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

Let's say I have lines of the form:

```
int[4] height
char c
char[50] userName 
char[50+foo("bar")] userSchool
```

As you see, the bracketed expression is optional.

Can I parse these strings using Lua's `string.match()` ?

The following pattern works for lines that contain brackets:

```
line = "int[4] height"
print(line:match('^(%w+)(%b[])%s+(%w+)$'))
```

But is there a pattern that can handle also the optional brackets? The following does **not** work:

```
line = "char c"
print(line:match('^(%w+)(%b[]?)%s+(%w+)$'))
```

Can the pattern be written in another way to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Unlike regular expressions, `?` in Lua pattern matches a single character.

You can use the `or` operator to do the job like this:

```
line:match('^(%w+)(%b[])%s+(%w+)$') or line:match('^(%w+)%s+(%w+)$')
```

A little problem with it is that Lua only keeps the first result in an expression. It depends on your needs, use an `if` statement or you can give the entire string the first capture like this

```
print(line:match('^((%w+)(%b[])%s+(%w+))$') or line:match('^((%w+)%s+(%w+))$'))
```

Comment: Thanks. I know about this solution, of calling `match()` twice. The problem is that I actually need to alter the string (`gsub()`, not `match()`; I left it out of the question for simplicity's sake) and I don't want the second call to gsub() to see the changes made by the first.

Comment: @NiccoloM. Why not ask a new question about using `string.gsub` to solve your original problem?

Answer (score 3):

[LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/lpeg.html) may be more appropriate for your case, especially if you plan to expand your grammar.

```
local re = require're'

local p = re.compile( [[
    prog <- stmt* -> set
    stmt <- S { type } S { name }
    type <- name bexp ?
    bexp <- '[' ([^][] / bexp)* ']'
    name <- %w+
    S    <- %s*
]], {set = function(...)
    local t, args = {}, {...}
    for i=1, #args, 2 do t[args[i+1]] = args[i] end
    return t
end})

local s = [[
int[4] height
char c
char[50] userName
char[50+foo("bar")] userSchool
]]

for k, v in pairs(p:match(s)) do print(k .. ' = ' .. v) end

--[[
c = char
userSchool = char[50+foo("bar")]
height = int[4]
userName = char[50]
--]]
```